# Google Guice property placeholder

Tags: java, properties, guice

I have a property file in my project which has internal references to other properties from the same file, or sometime system or environment variables. How can I refer to those in the same property file?

For example:

```
Test = testexample
foo = ${Test}/${hostname}
```

Here `Test` should come from the above property and `hostname` from system variables. This works with Spring.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Guice allows you to register properties via Names.bindProperties but does not provide an own mechanism to load the properties, so this is not supported.

When you manage to read/replace the properties with another tool, you can then register them, of course.

When you use maven, you could think about using the [build-helper](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/regex-property-mojo.html) plugin to replace the references during build, if this is sufficient for you.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't present in core Guice but can actually be achieved using the [Rocoto Guice extension](https://github.com/99soft/rocoto)

It allows placeholders to be specified and expands them dynamically

```
my.testFile = testFile.config
my.testDir = /etc
my.testPath = ${my.testDir}/${my.testFile}
```

It also supports default values

```
my.testDir = /etc

#resolves to /etc/default.config
my.testPath = ${my.testDir}/${my.testFile|default.config}
```